# pushing a datatable from memory into SQL server using ADO.NET

Tags: sql-server-2005, ado.net

I have a datatable in memory that I got from a non SQL source.
What is the most elegant way, using ADO.NET to push it "as is into a new SQL (2005) server table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to do this as a series of steps.  Firstly, creating the table via some dynamic SQL.  Then you'd need to load the information from memory into the newly created table, potentially using a `BULK INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

Or create the table on the SQL Server, read one row at a time, and add it to the table.

Answer (score 0):

- CREATE TABLE based on the structure
- SQLBulkCopy it